# Why is this query always slow

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, innodb

I have 3 ajax calls going off at once to run 3 queries. This one always takes a long time, sometimes 20-50 seconds. I can't figure out why.

```
select 
f.id, f.date, f.rating, f.comments, oi.sku, oi.sku_id 
FROM feedback f
left join orders o on o.warehouse_order_id = f.`AmazonOrderId`
left join orderItems oi on oi.order_id = o.id
where oi.client_id = $client_id && f.rating IN (4,5)
group by f.id
limit 20
```

Here's the explain:

```
id select_type table type   possible_keys                         key        key_len ref                   rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      f     index  AmazonOrderId                         PRIMARY    4       NULL                  40   Using where

1  SIMPLE      o     ref    PRIMARY,warehouse,warehouse_order_id  warehouse  603     mydb.f.AmazonOrderId  1    Using index

1  SIMPLE      oi    ref    order_id                              order_id   5       mydb.o.id             1    Using index condition; Using where
```

Even running by itself, directly in SQL. I get "No Errors, 20 rows affected taking 44.7 seconds"

edit: screenshot of explain with headers:

[image]
https://d3vv6lp55qjaqc.cloudfront.net/items/0L2m3P3s0J0p3u3T3l1F/%5Bf370a9e4778d50dc963ee7738fc0cf96%5D_Image%25202017-08-12%2520at%25203.47.07%2520PM.png?X-CloudApp-Visitor-Id=1090177

I have indexes on AmazonOrderId and orders.warehouse_order_id

Comment: Thanks for posting the EXPLAIN. Would you please repost it more legibly, with column headings and fixed size columns, maybe from /usr/bin/mysql? Also, does changing the `IN (4,5)` disjunction into `f.rating >= 4` change the plan at all?

Comment: Updated with screenshot of explain with headers

Comment: Changing to >= 4 doesn't change anything about the explain btw

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need the second `left join`.  The `where`clause turns the second into an inner join.  And, because it relies on the second table, that also should be an inner join.  The outer joins might hamper the optimizer.

Then, the `group by` seems unnecessary.  You have columns from `oi`, so aggregating by `f` doesn't make sense (most databases would return an error).  So:

```
select f.id, f.date, f.rating, f.comments, oi.sku, oi.sku_id 
from feedback f join
     orders o
     on o.warehouse_order_id = f.AmazonOrderId left join
     orderItems oi
     on oi.order_id = o.id
where oi.client_id = $client_id and f.rating IN (4,5)
limit 20
```

For this, I would recommend the normal indexes on `join` keys.  You might also want an index on `feedback(rating, AmazonOrderId)`.

Comment: Thanks! If you don't include the `group by` you get duplicate results. Because there are multiple "items" in an order. But the order is what a feedback relates to. Even though an item is what relates to a client. So if there were 2 items in 1 order, this would return the same feedback twice.

Comment: All of the 4 keys involved in the 2 joins have indexes

Comment: Also I added that combo index and the query still takes about 13 seconds. I should note all other queries, include ones that affect more data than this, take < 1 up to 1.5 seconds at most.

Comment: @SeanClark, in SQL, *Distinct* is used to get rid of duplicates. *Group By* is for applying aggregate functions.

Comment: Good call, I've changed that, the query is still slow however.

Comment: It doesn't look like o.id  is indexed.  Why is feedback joined to order on warehouse_order_id but orderItems is joined on id?  I agree with Gordon that this syntax should fail because of the group by.

Comment: Using distinct or group by only eliminates duplicate items within the order or items with the same sku and sku_id.  It doesn't actually remove duplicates so you'd show the feedback per order once.  It looks like you're repeating the feedback once per unique item.  Nothing to do with performance but maybe the design is the issue.

Comment: @SeanClark . . . What item goes into the columns in the `SELECT` if there are multiple items in an order?  The query doesn't make sense with the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: It's main objective is to select from the feedback table. It needs to get to orderItems to get the client_id. And you need orders to get from freedback to orderItems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is where things go astray:

```
left join orders o on o.warehouse_order_id = f.AmazonOrderId
```

There are several candidate keys, and for reasons I can't discern the optimizer picked "the wrong one". It ignored the index on warehouse_order_id that we would prefer it to use.

Sometimes an index is disabled for a query because a function obscures it, e.g. testing string equality against LOWER(indexed_column). Sometimes it is more subtle, like SHOW CREATE TABLE reveals that latin1 collation is used by one table or column, and utf8mb4 is used by the other join participant.
Try adding `use index (warehouse)` and see if the plan changes.

Also, it looks like `f` is the driving table. Since `oi.client_id = $client_id` enjoys good selectivity, it seems like we'd want the plan to start with `oi`, use that to probe `o`, and finally arrive at `f`. Does listing the 3 tables in reverse order affect the plan at all?

Comment: I tried reversing the order starting with oi, but same 14 second run time. I noticed that key warehouse and key warehouse_order_id are the duplicate, so I removed warehouse. It say it's using key warehouse_order_id now, and order_id. But it's still slow reverse or normal.

Comment: I've also confirmed that warehouse_order_id and AmazonOrderId are both UTF-8 Unicode (utf8) and Collation utf8_general_ci. Both varchar(200) as well

Comment: @Sean Clark I misread the explain plan.  It looked like there was an index of columns warehouse and warehouse_order_id.  My mistake.  I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create an index on orders.id 

The left joins were changed to inner joins because the where clause on client_id implicitly changes it to an inner join.
```

```
select f.id, f.date, f.rating, f.comments, oi.sku, oi.sku_id 
from feedback f
     inner join orders o on o.warehouse_order_id = f.AmazonOrderId
     inner join orderItems oi on oi.order_id = o.id -- should this be o.warehouse_order_id?
where oi.client_id = $client_id && f.rating IN (4,5)
group by f.id
limit 20
```

Comment: I added the client_id index, that makes the query only take 5-6 seconds. So much better. warehouse_order_id isn't the key because it's a separate ID, and not all orders will have a warehouse_order_id.  order_items.id relates to orders.id because they are the children of orders.

Comment: @Sean Clark Okay I changed the answer for just this index.  I think making warehouse_order_id the first column in its index would also improve performance.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by making it the first column in the index? For the orders table, it's the only column in it's index `KEY ‘warehouse_order_id’ (‘warehouse_order_id’),` I think I'm not following your suggestion there. Thanks!

Comment: Suppose we select c1, c2 from an indexed table where c1 is in some range, and c0 is the primary key. It is common for an indexed query to do sequential reading of index blocks from the disk, plus random reads of the base table, in this case to retrieve the required c2 value. Creating a compound index on (c1, c2) would produce a covering index for this query, an index that offers all required values to satisfy the query without random seeks into table storage. See also https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/11/23/covering-index-and-prefix-indexes/ or google or wikipedia.

Comment: A covered index wasn't needed here.  Sean just needed to add an index on orders.id which he confirmed.